# UX design Process Vary from designer to designer, Which design process is commonly used by designers in worldwide

Tags: design-process

I interacted with different designers, they do design with their own process. their prospective are also different. some of them use different laws like (hicks law, gestalt theory and many more). so its takes time to work with a Designer as a team, in where designer having their own process.
is there any common process that's used widely ?

Comment: I have also worked with many different designers who employ many different processes but find this useful as it brings different perspectives and viewpoints giving a better finished product - I don't see this as a problem. Like my note here, this question will prompt many different opinions of what is good or bad about multiple processes and which processes are best and I think it's probably too opinion-based for this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design processes vary among designers and among organizations. I doubt you'll find any universal design processes.

A lot of us work in Agile environments, but even then, I've found that UX Design is most comfortable outside of the sprint cycle. The best UX process I've seen is when the UX team does our research and design and iteration (in collaboration with Business Analysts, etc) until the element we're working on is ready for development. Then the BAs' user stories, linked with our prototypes, are scheduled into sprints. We then evaluate and tweak as the feature is built.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking about UX designers in particular I would say that they are well adjusted for scrum/agile processes. However, I would say the overall encompassing process is an iterative design process.